# Hide Notch on macOS Sonoma while using a video wallpaper

Tags: macos, wallpaper

Just as the title describes.

I am looking for a way to [hide the notch](https://topnotch.app/_nuxt/img/menubar@2x.240cd40.png) on macOS while using the [new video wallpapers](https://www.macrumors.com/2023/08/30/macos-sonoma-beta-7-wallpapers/). Apps like [TopNotch](https://topnotch.app) work awesome with dynamic wallpapers but not Sonoma's new video wallpapers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only time I notice the notch is when other people ask about how to hide it.